# I am facing problem of U+FB00, U+FB02

Tags: symbols, packages, unicode, input-encodings

I am using Texmaker for practicing, While practicing tex, I encountered 3 errors that are as follows:

1. ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ﬀ (U+FB00)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ...ng Rigaku Miniﬂex II desktop X-ray diﬀ2
2. ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ﬂ (U+FB02)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ...(XRD) was carried out using Rigaku Miniﬂ
3. ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ﬀ (U+FB00)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ...l and elemental determination. X-ray diﬀ

I was using the following packages:

```
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

I tried all the possible methods to remove them, but all of them went in vein. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will probably hard to give an answer to this question without further information. Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: @Vadiraj KT, that means copy and paste the minimum inputs of your file that produces the above errors.

Comment: These are Unicode ligatures in your document source. Do a search-and-replace of U+FB00 with `ff`, etc.

Comment: You could also set up `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to insert some visible symbol in the document that tells you where the special characters you copied and pasted are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You copied and pasted into your document source some Unicode text that contained the ligatures ﬀ (U+FB00) and ﬂ (U+FB02).  (This should not happen if you compiled the document you copied from with modern fonts.)

Do a search-and-replace to replace `ﬀ` with `ff` and `ﬂ` with `fl`.

You could also `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to do the replacement automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, replacing ff and fl worked out and the file executed.